# Jquery/Ajax | Как перезагрузить картинку которая в <canvas>

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Сложно уместить код в эту тему, попробую на словах. В html теге  js генерирует картинку, на основе той что лежит в папке, если я захочу поменять картинку что в ней лежит с помощью ajax то всё-равно картинка отобразиться только после перезагрузки страницы.

Проблема похожа на ту когда картинка находиться в теге img, там нужно обновить src, но тут в теге  такого нет.

Я попытался скрипт что берёт картинку из папки обернуть в функцию и вызывать после выполнения ajax. И это работает раз через раз, и то нужно эту функцию вызывать дважды.

Понимаю, понять что я тут хочу трудно, но может кто-то да поможет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "Сложно уместить код в эту тему" -- есть куча сервисов, в которых можно разместить свой код ([раз](https://codepen.io/), [два](https://jsfiddle.net/)), а здесь приложить на него ссылку. А здесь указать и объяснить ключевые моменты